# Rails - Association between two models with foreign key having different names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

I have two models , Agent , Visit .

```
Class Agent 
:name

Class Booking 
:booked_by
```

I want a has many relation where an agent can have multiple bookings. I want the key to be name/booked by .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `foreign_key` option like so:

```
class Agent < AR::Base
  has_many :bookings, :foreign_key => :booked_by
end

class Booking < AR::Base
  belongs_to :agent, :foreign_key => :booked_by
end
```

From`has_many` [doc](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many) and`belongs_to` [doc](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/belongs_to).

Comment: This worked .  I had to add     `self.primary_key = "name"`,   in Agent model .

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

Class Agent

```
has_many    :names, class_name: 'Booking'
```

Class Booking

```
belongs_to  :booked_by, class_name: 'Agent'
```